# Putting option to select using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

Code doesn't work. Array is correct but func append and `$("#pairId").attr("disable", 0);` doesn't work.

```
function setClientCur(clientcur) {
  var coCurList = JSON.parse('<?=json_encode($this->To)?>');
  var currClientCurr = coCurList[clientcur];

  $("#pairId").attr("disable", 0);

  for (var arg in currClientCurr) {
    $("#pairId").append('<option value="' + currClientCurr[arg]['pairId'] + '">' + currClientCurr[arg]['coCurTitle'] + '</option>');
  }
}
```

Comment: Assuming you want to enable the `select` element, use `removeAttr('disabled')` or `prop('disabled', false)`. If that's not  what you're trying to do, please edit the question so that your intent is *much* clearer

Comment: you are right. now all works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#pairId").attr("disable", 0);
```

This is not the way how it is done.
You can do it like this:

```
$("#pairId").prop("disabled", false);
```